# install EventFilter on QWidget (qt4.4.3/kde4)

Tags: qt, event-handling, widget, kde-plasma

I have a K* window, and within it, a widget which needs the events filtered.

For example I do not want the possibility of clicking it...

How can I do that?

Have I to use eventfilters? In this case, what's the best way?

---

but my problem is that I can't subclass my widget,because it's a TerminalInterface->widget(), not an object like others :\

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides the setEnabled sledgehammer approach in the first answer, there are two other approaches, one of which is to use eventfilters.

The other is to subclass the widget, and then reimplement, say, the mouse* events. Simply leaving them empty will prevent any mouse interaction. So:

MyWidget : public QSomeWidget
{
     Q_OBJECT
public:
     MyWidget(QWidget *parent);

protected:
     void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *) {}
     .. etc ..
};

Comment: but my problem is that I can't subclass my widget,because it's a 

TerminalInterface->widget()

Answer (score 1):

QWidget has an `enabled` property.  Just call `widget->setEnabled(false)` and this will prevent it from accepting mouse clicks.  It may also modify its appearance: for example a `QPushButton` will be grayed out.

Event Filters sound like overkill for what you want.

Comment: It isn't the thing I want. 

I need to *filter* the events, not to disable them...

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `eventFilter()` is what you want.

Here's the section of Qt docs that talk about it:
[Event Filters](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/eventsandfilters.html#event-filters)

Basically you have to create a class that inherits `QObject` and then implement the virtual function `eventFilter()`.  Then call the [installEventFilter()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#installEventFilter) method on the object that you want to filter with the filter as a parameter.